# Fatal error NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type after xcode10.1 update

Tags: ios, swift

since I update the xcode 10.1, this error occur.

The code is:

```
class mainPageJobObj   {
    var _id : String = ""
    var avatar :String = ""
    var name : String = ""
    var serviceState = ""
}
items : [mainPageJobObj]!
items // i read it from server and its not empty
let oneItem = items[index] // Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type -- This is what compiler is showing.
```

[image: after debuging]
[image: debuging more specefic]

Comment: The short answer is that `items` doesn't contain instances of `mainPageJobObj`. You need to show `readItemsFromServer` for a better answer

Comment: `ReadItemsFromServer()` is not returning the array of `mainPageJobObj` here.

Comment: actually i read it from server it before and i dont use this class but for simplicity i put this class in declaration. i debug it and its not empty!

Comment: You can see from your debug screenshot that `items` is an array of dictionaries, not an array of `mainPageJobObj`

Comment: it is very hard to understand the issue when you have posted only fragments of your code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i add another picture to be more specific , as you can see in my second pic its not empty nor dic!

Comment: When you print `type(of: items)` it says that it is `[mainPageJobObj]` because that is how you declared it to Swift, **but**, when Swift tries to access an element it finds an `NSMutableArray` and you get an exception.  `type(of:)` shows the Swift type, not the actual contents of a bridged `NSArray`

Comment: I do not understand what you want to say with `debuging more specefic`. The output of `type(of: items)` being `Array<mainPageJobObj>` does not mean its actual contents are `mainPageJobObj`. In fact, this mismatching is causing the error. Unless you show how you get `items` (`slider_mainPageObj.items`), you may need to read many more useless guesses.

Comment: This has been said by others already but  I do it anyway. **1.** you declare a variable to be an array of a specific type. **2.** you assign an array to your variable that is of a different type (dictionary). **3.** you try to read from your array variable and this is where you are faced with the consequences of point 1 and 2.

Comment: @Nadia did you find answer yet or no? After update?

Comment: @HarjotSingh no I didn't yet but I find out the problem do not related to xcode update.

Comment: @Nadia did u try Mr. Paul answer? He is giving very good solution to overcome it from the root.

Comment: @HarjotSingh  yes he was right the problem was the type of array , the convertor didn't works correctly. I Fix it

Comment: @Nadia how did you fix it, please kindly share it? or Post as your own answer?

Comment: @HarjotSingh I use Alamofire  for converting json string(which is read from server) to my custom object, I didn't know what did happen suddenly the conversion didn't works well as you can see in a picture, the type of array in my object is NSDictionary which shouldn't be. i just go down in my project git extension where it works well and now i am continuing to develop my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that `items` was bridged from an `NSArray` (which does not enforce typing of its elements) but when Swift tried to retrieve an element, it did not find an instance of `mainPageJobObj`, which is what you said they array contained.

From the debug screen shot you can see that the `items` array actually contains instances of `NSMutableDictionary`.

A quick fix is to use the appropriate declaration of `items`:

```
var items:[String:Any] = slider.mainPageObj.items!
let oneItem = items[index]
let name = oneItem["name"]
```

A much better fix is to use Swift types from the start;  If the data from your server is being returned in JSON format then use `Codable` to create Swift Struct or Class instances.

Comment: the data from server is parsed from dic to [mainPageJobObj] by EVReflection ( https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection ),i want the items type be [mainPageJobObj] not a dic! it works before updating xcode!

Comment: I don't know anything about `EVReflection` or what might have changed - You have been asked repeatedly to show the code that fetches your data and creates the array.  What I can tell you is that you have an array of dictionaries and that is causing your crash.  BTW Xcode 10.2 is now released

Comment: man you sure saved me! with the update to xcode 12.4 i had a similar problem with MLVision, but your approach was an excellent solution.